# C++ volatile Interrupt ISR DMA

Tags: c++, embedded, interrupt, volatile, dma

I know there is a lot of confusion regarding volatile.

So I have 3 real life examples I'm not sure about the correct usage of volatile.

**1) DMA Stream** 
The hardware writes directly to data with DMA. 
Is volatile needed in this span?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <semaphore>
#include <span>

static std::binary_semaphore semaphore{0};

//DMA Interrupt after complete receive
extern "C" void DMAcomplete() {
    semaphore.release();
}

void readFromDMA(std::span<volatile uint8_t> data) {
    //Modify DMA register and start DMA
    //... = data.data();

    //wait for DMA to finish
    semaphore.acquire();
}
```

**2) ISR read** 
This example is similar to the first one, but now the ISR is actually manipulating the data. 
Is volatile needed in the span?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <semaphore>
#include <span>
#include <atomic>

static std::binary_semaphore semaphore{0};

static std::atomic<volatile uint8_t*> data;
static std::atomic_size_t size;
static std::atomic_size_t index;

//Interrupt is called per byte
extern "C" void ISRperByte() {
    uint8_t receivedData;

    data[index++] = receivedData;

    //Receive complete
    if(index >= size-1)
        semaphore.release();
}

void readFromISR(std::span<volatile uint8_t> toRead) {
    
    data = toRead.data();
    size = toRead.size();
    index = 0;

    //Enable Interrupt etc.

    //Wait until all reads are done
    semaphore.acquire();
}
```

**3) ISR Callback** 
Does ICallback* have to be volatile?

```
#include <atomic>

class ICallback {
public:
    virtual ~ICallback() = default;
    virtual void doStuff() volatile = 0;
};

static std::atomic<volatile ICallback*> atomicCallback = nullptr;

//Interrupt is called by hardware
extern "C" void ISR() {
    auto cb = atomicCallback.load();
    if(cb)
        cb->doStuff();
}

void setCallback(ICallback& cb) {
    atomicCallback = &cb;
}

void resetCallback() {
    atomicCallback = nullptr;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is s snippet of case 1 using C

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//Assume assigment to this is atomic
static volatile bool semaphore;

//DMA Interrupt after complete receive
void DMAcomplete() {
    
    //notify 
    semaphore = 1;
}

void readFromDMA(volatile uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) {
    semaphore = 0;
    //Modify DMA register and start DMA
    //... = data.data();

    //wait for DMA to finish
    while(semaphore != 1);
}
```

EDIT2: 
If I call `readfromDMA` or `readfromISR` with none volatile data, is it valid after the function returns? Since the caller doesn't declare his data as volatile, but the data is changed during DMA/ISR, it seems a little suspicious.

Comment: volatile is usually only needed for memory mapped io and has nothing todo with threadsafety or atomicity. It tells the compiler not to optimize out any reads or writes to memory. So it basically guarantees that everything you write to a memory address will be written, and every read will read from that memory will actually be executed (so no data is cached or put in registers)

Comment: @PepijnKramer DMA and ISRs have nothing to do with thread safety either. Similar but not quite... it's much lower level concepts than threads. As for guarantees of what get cached or not, `volatile` is not a safe bet. One needs to ensure that a DMA buffer doesn't get cached through some other means, depending on target.

Comment: @Lundin fair enough. I've only used volatile once or twice on simple processors and that was ages ago. So the cache stuff is a bit out of my experience.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Anyway, with pure C it would be rather easy to answer and predict what machine code that's generated. So what exactly is C++ adding here? The opportunity to make already complex hardware mechanics even more confusing and complex just for the heck of it? If you can't tell what machine code that's generated from your higher layer language code, then don't write that code. You can't write drivers with trial & error fumbling around in the dark. At a minimum you have to disassemble all of this. And again and again each time you make the slightest change.

Comment: @Lundin the problem is the same in C besides atomics and semaphore are implemented different.

Comment: And span, and default constructors, and CRT initialization behavior, and member function qualifiers, and-...

Comment: @Lundin I've added an example in C maybe you could tell me if data has to be volatile.

Comment: In your C example the bool called semaphore absolutely does have to be volatile (@PepijnKramer learn that this is nothing to do with mapped-IO and everything to do with concurrency)  Whether the data has to be volatile depends on what you do with it.  To start the DMA you probably just want its address, which doesn't depend on whether what it points to is volatile.

Comment: See [Using volatile in embedded C development](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102). My answer there also addresses atomicity and race conditions. What's not mentioned is DMA buffers - those are to be regarded as hardware registers so they should be `volatile` and mid- to high-end MCUs with data cache shouldn't be allowed to cache them.

Comment: "_I know there is a lot of confusion regarding volatile_" - yep, and some of the comments to this question confirm that!  It does a simple thing, often it is not the solution the user thinks it is, but that does not mean it is not needed, simply that it may not on its own be a complete solution.  Issues of cache coherency and atomicity for example are not solved by `volatile`.  It seldom does any harm (other than it can defeat some optimisations, but if you need the memory to be explicitly accessed, the optimisation would be unwanted in any case), so if in doubt...

Comment: @Clifford "It seldom does any harm" Hmm well... recent RL example. I peeked at this code base by a less experienced dev and they had declared every single file scope variable `volatile` - because they had been burnt by incorrect optimizations of variables shared with an ISR before, then scolded by me for not using volatile. The result of this was quite some code bloat because of blocked optimizations - everything worked but the executable was some 10kb larger than necessary and on the border to forcing a swap to the next larger MCU in the family. So too much `volatile` can be harmful too :)

Comment: @Lundin : Sure, my advice was not to "_use it everywhere_".  When I said "if in doubt", I would not expect a developer who understood `volatile` semantics to doubt _every_ variable. To be clear: liberally sprinkling `volatile` is no substitute for actually understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our compiler says this about volatile declared Objects:

> ● All accesses are preserved 
> ● All accesses are complete, that is, the whole object is accessed 
> ● All accesses are performed in the same order as given in the abstract machine 
> ● All accesses are atomic, that is, they cannot be interrupted. 
> The compiler adheres to these rules for accesses to all 8-, 16-, and 32-bit scalar types. 
> For all combinations of object types not listed, only the rule that states that all accesses
> are preserved applies.

So for the examples the following would be correct:

1. **DMA** 
   Volatile is not needed in `readFromDMA`.
   BUT the data which is passed to this function has to be volatile for example `std::vector<volatile uint8_t>`.
2. **ISR read** 
   In this example the volatile in `data` is indeed needed, because the ISR manipulates it. Additionally, as in example 1, volatile is also needed in the declaration of the buffer for example `std::vector<volatile uint8_t>`.
3. **ISR Callback** 
   `ICallback*` does not need to be volatile, BUT the object implementing `doStuff` has to be aware, that this function is called from an ISR. So it may need some volatile member.